# Document - How to get a tag's value by its name?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using Java's DOM parser to parse an XML file.

let's say I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <dotcms>
        <endPoint>ip</endPoint>
    </dotcms>
</config>

</xml>
```

I like to get the value of 'endPoint'. I can do it with the following code snippet. (assuming that I already parsed it with DocumentBuilder)

```
NodeList nodeList = this.doc.getElementByTagName("dotcms");
Node nValue = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
return nValue.getNodeValue();
```

Is it possible to get a value of a field by a field's name? Like....

`Node nValue = nodeList.getByName("endPoint")` something like this...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [XPath](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) for these sorts of tasks:

```
//endPoint/text()
```

or:

```
/config/dotcms/endPoint/text()
```

Of course Java has a built-in [support](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) for XPath:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//endPoint/text()");
Object value = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Comment: // Great!! I appreciate it! Short, but useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), a [jquery](http://jquery.org)-like DOM wrapper, to write even less code:

```
// Using css-style selectors
String text1 = $(document).find("endPoint").text();

// Using XPath
String text2 = $(document).xpath("//endPoint").text();
```