# xsd traversing in java

Tags: java, xsd, xsom

How to traverse XSD using java and put into some data structure? I want to traverse XSD and collect all attributes and their constraints(like min./max values)  The options i see are XSOM([Parsing XSD Schema with XSOM in Java. How to access element and complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948389/parsing-xsd-schema-with-xsom-in-java-how-to-access-element-and-complex-types)) which is not maintained. Other option is to use JAXB, to create Java classes and then use reflection to get all the attributes which looks time consuming.
Is there any other way ?

Comment: The XSD is done for JAXB. You compile the XSD using JAXB, it will create java classes that respect all the criteria you're mentioning (max value, min value, number of occurrences etc.) and you can use them directly being safe that they will respect the constraints.

Comment: Alternatively, if all you need is really to know the properties, then you can parse the XSD as a normal XML file and get the attributes using the standard Xerces library. But honestly it would mean you need to re-implement what is already well implemented and maintained by Jaxb.

Comment: Thanks. JAXB looks better option. But still reflection is necessary to get all the attribute names/properties.?

Comment: What is your real need? If you tell in the XSD that a field shouldn't take values larger than 10, the generated class will reject values larger than 10. Isn't that what you want (I guess not since you're still looking to find these values by reflection)?

Comment: Need is to get all the attributes(<xs:attribute>) and their properties. In current xsd, these are specified inside <xs:attribute><xs:simpleType><xs:minLength value= 4 </></xs:simpleType></xs:attribute>. Another alternative i have found is using xml schema core(https://ws.apache.org/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/apidocs/index.html) This approach looks straightforward.

Comment: In that case, you basically need to parse an XML file, no matter that it's an XSD. So you can easily use xerces or even JAXB itself (by defining the XSD structure into a POJO and then parsing it)

Comment: Thanks. Converting it to POJO and using reflection to get all fields details?

Comment: No, create a class with the fields that you want, then parse the XSD (which is an XML file in the end) into it to get access to the values without need of using reflection. See this: https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example

Comment: Thanks. XSD is more than 1000 lines with  many complex types. Writing POJO is a big task. I am looking for is something like  XSD walker, which can list complex types, their attributes(and their facets if any) etc. Based on this i want to write these complex types and attributes to Excel file. so given a XSD, write all complex types/attributes to Excel file. Thats the task.

Comment: What I mean is: the XSD is itself an XML file. So, if you create a POJO for the XSD (not for the objects actually described by the XSD), you are able to parse the XSD into your POJO. At that point, you'll have a structured object which contains getters for all you need to read (attributes, values etc.).

Comment: Thanks.. Writing POJO for xsd. Is there any tool or library?

Comment: Probably, but I don't know it. Also, I don't think you want the full XSD pojo, you only want to define the fields you're interested to (and not mapping the rest)